# Angular 11 - Dynamic contextmenu with changeable click events

Tags: angular, typescript, contextmenu

I'm trying to make a dynamic contextmenu with changeable click-event actions. I think I'm pretty close to solving it, but there is a major issue, I cant pass any parameters to the click-event action as will be shown below.

here is the code for the contextmenu item component

```
import { Component, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'contextmenu-item',
  template: `<span>{{ label }}</span>`,
  styleUrls: ['./contextmenu-item.component.scss']
})
export class ContextmenuItemComponent {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() public label: string = "default";

  @HostListener('click') public click!: (data: any) => void;

}
```

this is a little example of how I insert the menu items in the context menu with the ComponentFactoryResolver.

```
@ViewChild("contextmenu") $contextmenuComponent!: ContextmenuComponent;
@ViewChild("contextRef", {read: ViewContainerRef}) $ref!: ViewContainerRef;

openContextMenu(event: IGridCellEventArgs, documentGridBoundary: HTMLDivElement) {
    this.$contextmenuComponent.show(event, documentGridBoundary); // this line displays the menu 
                                                                     container
    
    const component = this.factory.resolveComponentFactory(ContextmenuItemComponent)
    const item1 = this.$ref.createComponent(component);
    //const item2 = this.$ref.createComponent(component);
    //const item3 = this.$ref.createComponent(component);

    item1.instance.label = "Open" ;
    item1.instance.clickAction = this.contextOpenDocument;  //this is the method I'm binding to the  
                                                              ContextmenuItemComponent click-event
}
```

As described, my major issue is that I cant pass parameters to the clickAction, I would like to pass the event parameters from "openContextMenu" to the clickAction.

EDIT:

Event better would be, how to i attach something like (click)="func()" to a component created like the one above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

In the ContextmenuItemComponent i can set up an event emitter to emit whenever its clicked. and subscribe to it when i create the component!